# Google Play 64-bit requirement

Tags: java, android, google-play, 64-bit, gpuimage

I'm trying to submit an update to my app, after uploading the **Android App bundle** I get this error message :

[image]

I've read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) and follow all steps, after analyzing the **Android App bundle** :

[image]

My app is a Photo Editor app, with pure java, I don't use any native code, but I used some third-party library such as

```
implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
```

which supports the 64 bit as you can see in the image above

here's my Gradle file :

```
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        dexOptions {
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "maa.abc"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 14
            versionName "1.2.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            renderscriptTargetApi 28
            renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' 'armeabi'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
            debug {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.annotations1'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':appintro')
    /*ANDROID*/
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'


    /*PHOTO FILTERS (CONTAINS NATIVE CODE)*/
    implementation 'cn.ezandroid:EZFilter:2.0.9'
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'

    /*ANIMATION*/
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'

    /*GLIDE*/
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'


    /*PICK IMAGE /TAKE PICTURE*/
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'

    /*TEST IMPLEMENTATION*/
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


    /*VIEWS*/
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.alexvasilkov:gesture-views:2.5.2'
    implementation('com.github.christophesmet:android_maskable_layout:v1.3.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.intellij', module: 'annotations'
    }
    implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.duanhong169:checkerboarddrawable:1.0.2'


    /*FIREBASE*/
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:5.0.0'

    /*HELPER*/
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.3'
    implementation 'com.github.nanchen2251:CompressHelper:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation(group: 'uz.shift', name: 'colorpicker', version: '0.5', ext: 'aar')

    /*CHANGING FONT*/
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
}
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

with this cmd I'm able to install my app on my phone successfully:

```
# A successful install:
> adb install --abi armeabi-v7a YOUR_APK_FILE.apk
Success
```

I tried to upload **.APK** but still I get the same error message, although I see my app support all native platforms :

[image]

Can anyone help me to get resolve this issue ?, I have spent almost 1 week to submit an update to my app with no success.

**UPDATE:**

**I have contacted google before 3 days ago, they said this :
Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support to report the behavior you're seeing with your App Bundle being flagged for 64 compliance. 
I’ve documented your issue and escalated it to our technical team for further investigation. Our team is working to resolve this issue for you as soon as possible.
I appreciate your patience and I’ll let you know the moment I have an update. 
If you have any other questions in the meantime, please let me know.**

Comment: Maybe try to compile that lib from source, as your project module, so you will get full control how it's compiled. That library looks no maintained anymore btw

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57361271/3633468

Comment: @user1209216 thank you so much for your comment, you're right the lastest version of it is **2.0.3**, but the latest version doesn't support 64bit, when I analyze the **.aab** I can't find the **libgpuimage-library.so**

Comment: @RKRK , thank you for your comment, can you please check the attached image in question,as you can see there's **x86_64** and **armb64-v8a** **.so** file

Comment: Perhaps not related to your problem, but you ought to drop `armeabi`, `mips`, and `mips64` from your list of supported ABIs. Such devices are pretty much nonexistent, and those ABIs aren't even supported by the Android NDK anymore.

Comment: @Michael ,I have removed them, but unfortunately, the message still appears and I can't submit my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after 1 week stuck in this situation, the problem was in **RenderScript** and **.bc** files, I have removed all **.bc** file from the project and removed those line as well.

```
renderscriptTargetApi 28
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

here's my final Gradle :

```
 compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maa.abc"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.9"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```