# Android app not 64 bit compliant after adding NDK { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' }

Tags: java, android-ndk, build.gradle, 64-bit

[image]

I'm a beginner in Android.
I was informed by Google that I needed 64bit support when registering the app and did the following.
After following Google's documentation how to make an android app 64 bit supplier here, the android app bundle I've been trying to build still is not 64 bit supplier.
But it doesn't work properly. If anyone suffers from these problems, ask for help.

A similar question asks me to delete the folder of jinilibs, and I think it would be good if you could tell me one more time exactly which one to delete.

This is the link to the question I referred to.

[Android app not 64 bit compliant after adding 'ndk { abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' }'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358403/android-app-not-64-bit-compliant-after-adding-ndk-abifilters-armeabi-v7a-a)

Comment: Go through your APK and find out which .so files it contains. Where do these .so files come from? If you're building them from source, then you should be fine (unless they contain architecture-specific assembly code / intrinsics that aren't provided for all ABIs). If they come as precompiled libraries included in some dependency you're using, then you'll have to find a version of that dependency that includes native libraries for all the ABIs you want to support. If there is no such version, then you're out of luck.

Comment: By the way, GnuSTL is deprecated. You should be using `c++_static` or `c++_shared`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 64bit support when registering the app. Check all of your libraries. maybe you are using old libraries.